# Getting higher accuracy in measuring AC voltage

Tags: ac, adc

I want to measure AC voltage to build an automatic voltage regulator.

First I use a transformer and this circuit to convert it to a DC voltage. Then I use an ADC to measure the DC voltage.

How can I get higher accuracy?

Is this circuit working fine in terms of practical design?

[image]

Comment: 'higher accurate' is not a specification. Do you want +/- 1%, +/- 1ppm, stable over time, or temperature?

Comment: Temperature I mean and changing resistor value

Comment: Adding an adjustable pot under R10 would give you accuracy for component variation. Temperature variation is a lot harder.

Comment: Wondering why you need to measure the AC in that accurately to regulate the output though.... Thinking this might be an XY problem.

Comment: i am just going to find appropriate way to measure ac , is this circuit good ?

Comment: Nope. LM324 will not like that negative input. Also seems to be a lot of components for a peak detector.

Comment: What do you want to measure? AC RMS? Peak? True accurate AC RMS measurement is not trivial given the harmonic content on the AC line so if that's what you're after you need a different approach.  (However @Trevor may have a point with this being an XY problem.)

Comment: i just want measure rms

Answer (score 1):

True RMS measurement of AC is a complex problem.   So, one generally doesn't
create a new solution, just buy a prebuilt module for the task  [typical RMS detector](http://www.analog.com/en/products/linear-products/rms-to-dc-converters/ad8436.html#product-overview) .   If the AC source is at known frequency and/or known waveform,
there are often other (simpler) approaches.

The DC output is somewhat delayed, so stabilizing an AC source using this kind
of sensing can be a problem.